# Java code to call Exacttarget Automation workflow: START

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, integration, soap, java

What is Java code to construct this SOAP?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-5501096" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>XXXXXXXXXX</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXXXXXXX</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
     <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Action>Start</Action>
         <Definitions>
            <Definition xsi:type="Program">
               <ObjectID>111111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555555555</ObjectID>
            </Definition>
         </Definitions>
      </PerformRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried this (ObjectID is changed):

```
// Configure Axis client with web service description file
EngineConfiguration config = new FileProvider( clientWSDD );        
// Create PartnerAPI stub with ExactTarget Web Service API endpoint and Axis configuration
PartnerAPI service = new PartnerAPILocator( config );
Soap stub = service.getSoap();

PerformRequestMsg performRequestMsg = new PerformRequestMsg();
performRequestMsg.setAction("START");

// Add retrieved automation objectID            
APIObject apiObject = new APIObject();
apiObject.setObjectID("111111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555555555");
performRequestMsg.setDefinitions(new APIObject[]{apiObject});

PerformResponseMsg response = stub.perform(performRequestMsg);
PerformResult[] res = response.getResults();
System.out.println("Response:: " + res[0].getStatusMessage());
```

Response:

```
Response:: Requested value 'APIObject' was not found.
```

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATED**
Finally, It is possible launch Automation via Java SDK(Axis), but with exception at the end.

```
String automationObjectID = "111111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555555555"; //Put here valid ObjectID
Automation automation = new Automation();
automation.setObjectID(automationObjectID);

PerformRequestMsg performRequestMsg = new PerformRequestMsg();
performRequestMsg.setAction("Start");

performRequestMsg.setDefinitions(new APIObject[]{automation});

PerformResponseMsg results = stub.perform(performRequestMsg);

if(results.getOverallStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("OK") && results.getResults() != null){
    logger.info("Execution status: " + results.getOverallStatus());
    logger.info("ObjectId:         " + results.getResults()[0].getStatusMessage());

}else{
    logger.error("Execution status: " + results.getOverallStatus());
    logger.error("ObjectId:         " + results.getResults()[0].getStatusMessage());
}
```

Response:

```
- External communication error is found
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.exacttarget.wsdl.partnerAPI.Automation - IsPlatformObject
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.exacttarget.wsdl.partnerAPI.Automation - IsPlatformObject
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.onStartChild(BeanDeserializer.java:258)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.exacttarget.wsdl.partnerAPI.SoapBindingStub.perform(SoapBindingStub.java:3258)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I have launched this soap(added real ObjectID) and I got OK response, but nothing happens...

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Axis, but I was able to successfully start a program using this CXF code:

```
Campaign campaign = new Campaign();
campaign.setCustomerKey("test");
PerformRequestMsg request = new PerformRequestMsg();
request.setAction("start");
Definitions definitions = new Definitions();
definitions.getDefinition().add(campaign);
request.setDefinitions(definitions);
PerformResponseMsg response = soap.perform(request);
```

SOAP request and response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    [...]
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Action>start</Action>
      <Definitions>
        <Definition xsi:type="Campaign">
          <CustomerKey>test</CustomerKey>
        </Definition>
      </Definitions>
    </PerformRequestMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    [...]
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <PerformResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Results>
        <Result>
          <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
          <StatusMessage>Campaign start performed</StatusMessage>
          <Object xsi:type="Campaign">
            <CustomerKey>test</CustomerKey>
            <Name>test</Name>
            <InteractionObjectID>baf155e9-4dad-434d-98c0-aba6f7740905</InteractionObjectID>
          </Object>
          <Task>
            <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
            <StatusMessage>6/10/2014 12:31:35 PM</StatusMessage>
            <ID>81673f3a-cd6d-414f-af16-591a3cfe3e6c</ID>
            <InteractionObjectID>baf155e9-4dad-434d-98c0-aba6f7740905</InteractionObjectID>
          </Task>
        </Result>
      </Results>
      <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
      <OverallStatusMessage/>
      <RequestID>df3cd39e-b1ef-4c82-915a-67449bca886f</RequestID>
    </PerformResponseMsg>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

More detail here (including an Axis example):

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/performing_a_campaign_via_the_web_service_api/

Let us know if you get this working.

-ian

Comment: I have copied Axis Java code from your link, added compaign code and got this error. Maybe campaign is not valid to be started? Result status:  Result code:    9999999 Result message: Exception occurred during [Perform::Start] ErrorID = 211022463

Comment: Can you post the new code here? -ian